# What is wrong with my idea of sampling from complicated distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

I started to read about a problem of sampling from a very complicated distribution. The [article state a problem](https://jeremykun.com/2015/04/06/markov-chain-monte-carlo-without-all-the-bullshit/) in the following way (not a citation):

> You have finite (potentially very big) $N$ elements and for each of
>   them you know their probability. You need to find an algorithm that
>   quickly draws me an element based on this distribution.

Most of the time, before reading something, I try to come up with my solutions and only after that I read suggested solutions. My first solution was kind of obvious:

- Uniformly select $N$. When you selected $N$ you know the probability of $N$. Now throw a biased coin and on success you basically select that $N$. On failure you redo everything again. It is clear that having a big $N$, I will spend huge amount of time redoing the drawing and this algorithm is inefficient.

My second approach is harder to describe, so I will use an example. Let $N=4$ and the probabilities are `[0.3, 0.05, 0.25, 0.4]`. So my approach is to construct the cumulative sum `[0.3, 0.35, 0.6, 1]`. Now find the smallest divisible factor (not what is the right term, but something similar to [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) for fractions) for the probabilities. Here it will be $0.05$. Now uniformly draw a number from 0 to 20 (1/0.05). Multiply this by smallest divisible factor and check to what region in our cumulative sum array it belongs.

This approach looks more feasible and the only problem I see right now is when the smallest divisible factor is too small, which results in too big region to draw a uniform number.

---

I quickly looked at the suggested solution and it is Metropolis-Hasting algorithm, which has nothing to do with what I proposed. Which means that there are some big problems with my approach.

So can anyone show me why my approach is inefficient (or may be totally wrong).

Comment: "(not a citation)" It shows... frankly, the statement is not very clear. It's not clear if $N$ is the amount of possible values that the variable can take (support of a discrete distribution) or number of samples to generate or what. Could you post the article, or a more careful formulation? If all you want to do is to generate a random variable following a (discrete , finite) probability function, then you are on the right track (though there are better ways). But if the "Metropolis-Hasting algorithm" is the solution, then it suggests that the problem is actually different.

Comment: @leonbloy I added a link to the article. The problem description starts at `The Problem is Drawing from a Distribution`. N is the amount of possible values that the variable can take.

Comment: Uniformly draw a probability $0\leq q_S \leq 1$, then start with $q_0=1$ and iterate through the list taking $q_{i+1}=(q_i-p_i)$, stop when $q_i \leq q_S$. Perhaps that would work?

Comment: @Emil sorry, I have not understood you. My first algorithm is kind of irrelevant to the question. I believe my second algorithm works correctly (so no need to change it). I just believe that it is inefficient but can't find why.

Comment: What happens if the probabilities are irrational? Then your smallest divisible factor won't exist...

Comment: I was thinking like this. Say you draw 0.6. Then it becomes 1-0.3=0.7>0.6. Next 0.7-0.05=0.65>0.6. Next 0.65-0.25=0.5<=0.6. Number three is the winner. This was my idea. But it probably doesnt work.

Comment: The idea of the linked article seems to be related to problems for which it is not possible (or at least not practical) to construct the entire cumulative probability table. Assuming otherwise has led us down a wrong path, I think. If we can restrict $N$ to a small enough number (perhaps in the billions or even trillions, but still much smaller than implied by the article), then inverse transform sampling is a simple and efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method you propose is the simplest form of **rejection sampling**, using a uniform proposal distribution.  It will be problematic if there are many outcomes with low probability; e.g., $$\Pr[N = x] = \begin{cases} 10^{-6}, & x \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 10^5\} \\ 0.9, & x = 0. \end{cases}$$  In such a scenario, you would take a very long time to obtain one realization, since the probability of choosing $N = 0$ is very small, and the rest of the time, the chance of accepting any $N > 0$ is also very unlikely.  You have already correctly identified the flaw in this approach.

The second method you propose is a form of **inverse transform sampling**, modified for discrete outcomes.  This is certainly better than the first method, but your implementation is problematic when the spacing between cumulative probabilities does not admit a sufficiently large common increment, again as you correctly identified.

If you simply performed true inverse transform sampling, this would be better:  refer to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) on the topic.

Regarding Metropolis-Hastings, the benefit of this method has to do with the ability to sample from distributions with very high dimensions in a way that sacrifices independence (i.e., realizations are autocorrelated) but gains increased probability of acceptance and therefore computational efficiency.  You generally don't really have this problem in a discrete case with one dimension, even if the number of outcomes is large.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have computed the cumulative sums of the probabilities
$\sum_{i=1}^k p_i$, simply choose $X$ uniformly over $[0,1]$, then use binary search to find the two cumulative sums that $X$ lies between. 
If $X$ lies between $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i$, then choose element number $k$.

The computational cost has two main parts: 
(1) the cost of constructing a list of
cumulative sums on which you can do the binary search,
and (2) the binary search.
Part (2) of the cost is incurred every time you draw a random
element from your set of $N$ elements, but it costs only $O(\log N)$ time
for each element drawn (because of the binary search).
Part (1) only needs to be done once for a given distribution,
and then you can draw random elements as many times as you like using
the same list of sums.

---

But the method above assumes that it is practical to construct a
list of the cumulative probabilities.
Looking at the first two paragraphs after "The Problem is Drawing from a Distribution" in 
https://jeremykun.com/2015/04/06/markov-chain-monte-carlo-without-all-the-bullshit/,
the space from which we want to sample is the space of all possible baby names.
To help us do this, we are given a "magic box" (much like one of the "oracles" favored by theoretical computer science) that takes a string
as input and outputs the probability that this string would be chosen
as a baby name.

How large is the sample space? Without a lot of information about the
working of the "magic box" (and the "magic" implies we know very little
of that), we cannot rule out any seemingly random concatenation of
syllables such as "Dweezil", nor long names such as
"Rumplestiltskin", nor concatenations of other names such 
"Philomenakatharinedelilah" -- in other words, the state space is *huge.*
Based on a back-of-the-envelop calculation,
"larger than the existing storage capacity of the human race" 
seems a low estimate.

If we assume we have at least a little a priori knowledge about the
responses the "magic box" will give, for example that "Emily" will be
much more likely than "Jenniferabellannamariedummy",
we can set up partial table of cumulative probabilities using all the
names in a large database of names actually given, which will
cover all but the extremely rare names.
Moreover, if we have a deterministic algorithm to generate strings of letters (other than these names) so that more plausible "names" are produced earlier in the sequence of outputs, heuristically we might hope as
we feed these names to the "magic box" the probabilities will accumulate
much faster than we would achieve by a more "uniform" method of
choosing random strings as names.

The idea here is that the stored data set, while initially fairly large,
is well within the storage capacity of commonly-available computing
platforms, and that even if we choose to extend our data set as we
sample new names from our "name-generating" algorithm,
the data set will still grow much more slowly than the number of
times we sample the probability space.
(There are ways to make it grow *very* slowly by storing only a subset of
the cumulative probabilities we calculate.)

---

As for the "solution" in the linked article, I'll confess I don't see what
it has to do with the problem. Perhaps it's treating names as a finite
multidimensional space, with each letter being one of the dimensions,
but if so I missed that explanation.

Comment: I do not see anything inefficient here. So why should one use complicated Metropolis-Hasting algorithm if they can do this?

Comment: N is potentially very big. I.e. step 1 would never finish. This is why I think calculating the cumulative sum on the fly might be good.

Comment: We have a very big harddrive?

Comment: So you want to go through several gazillion exabytes of data before even starting? That would be some launch time for the program. Phew. But I have used this algorithm and it worked fine then, its just that the question said N could be very big.

Comment: But on the fly calculation just needs 3*number of bytes for one number in space, which is nice. Or maybe two. not sure.

Comment: Not if they are readonly ;b

Comment: It would probably be best to save the current cdf value and corresponding index every year or so, though. best of both worlds!

Comment: @Emil I wrote my previous comments before actually reading the article. The problem as stated there is considerably less well-behaved than I assumed. We could have had a completely different conversation about it.